# Validating forms Ajax PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The jQuery/JavaScript/Ajax code is not mine. I'm learning and trying to understand it. The issue that I am having is after the data gets sent to the database the form is suppose to add `class="show"` to `#sendmessage` but its adding `class="show"` to `#errormessage` even though it was successful and the data was entered into the database. I don't understand why or how to fix it.

contact form index.html

```
 <div class="form">
                    <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
                    <div id="errormessage"></div>
                    <form action="contactform/contactform.php" method="POST" role="form" class="contactForm">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                                <div class="validation"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                                <div class="validation"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:8" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                            <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

contactform.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  //Contact
  $('form.contactForm').submit(function() {
    var f = $(this).find('.form-group'),
      ferror = false,
      emailExp = /^[^\s()<>@,;:\/]+@\w[\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/i;

    f.children('input').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'email':
            if (!emailExp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'checked':
            if (! i.is(':checked')) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'regexp':
            exp = new RegExp(exp);
            if (!exp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validation').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') !== undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    f.children('textarea').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validation').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') != undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    if (ferror) return false;
    else var str = $(this).serialize();
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    if( ! action ) {
      action = 'contactform/contactform.php';
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: action,
      data: str,
      success: function(msg) {
         //alert(msg);
        if (msg == 'OK') {
          $("#sendmessage").addClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").removeClass("show");
          $('.contactForm').find("input, textarea").val("");
        } else {
          $("#sendmessage").removeClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").addClass("show");
          $('#errormessage').html(msg);
        }

      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

contactform.php

```
<?php
//Define access
define('_VALID', 'Yes');
//required files
require_once('../include/config/config.php');

//variables
$contactFormName = '';
$contactFormEmail = '';
$contactFormSubject = '';
$contactFormMessage = '';
$checkStep = 1;

//Add new message
if (isset($_POST['name'])){ 


        //Get values
        $contactFormName = $_POST['name'];
        $contactFormEmail = $_POST['email'];
        $contactFormSubject = $_POST['subject'];
        $contactFormMessage = $_POST['message'];


        // 1. check name form field
        if($checkStep == 1){
            if($contactFormName === $_POST['name']){
                $contactFormName = filterName($contactFormName);
                $checkStep++;

            }else{
                echo "No its not working";
            }
        }
            // 2. check email field
            if($checkStep == 2){
                if($contactFormEmail === $_POST['email']){
                    $contactFormEmail = filterEmail($contactFormEmail);
                    $checkStep++;
                }else{
                        echo "Uh Oh! Something went wrong with your email please try again!";
                    }
                }

            // 3. check subject
            if($checkStep == 3){
                if($contactFormSubject === $_POST['subject']){
                    $contactFormSubject = filterSubject($contactFormSubject);
                    $checkStep++;
                }else{
                    echo "Uh Oh! Whats up with your subject";
                }
            }
            // 4. check message
            if($checkStep == 4){
                 if($contactFormMessage === $_POST['message']){
                    $contactFormMessage = filterMessage($contactFormMessage);
                     $checkStep++;
                }else{
                    echo "Uh ho!  Please write us a message";
                }
            }
            // 5. insert message
            if($checkStep == 5){
                $sqlAddMessage = "
                    INSERT INTO contact_form(
                        name,
                        email,
                        subject,
                        message
                    ) VALUES(
                        '$contactFormName', 
                        '$contactFormEmail', 
                        '$contactFormSubject', 
                        '$contactFormMessage'
                    )
                ";
                $queryAddMessage = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->query($sqlAddMessage);

                if($queryAddMessage){

                //code goes here
                }


            }else{
                echo "Uh Oh! NO No No. Check step 5";
            }
        }


?>
```

Comment: just tell your php to respond `OK` if the insertion went well. right now, it's tellin nothin that's why it kept on going to your `else` statement in the ajax success block

Comment: @Kevin can you give me an example?  I'm still learning about this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're not setting $msg = "OK" anywhere in your function so the AJAX response is always going to the else statement.

contactform.php (in // 5. section)

```
if($queryAddMessage){
    echo "OK";
}
```

Comment: I've tried   ```if($queryAddMessage){
    echo "OK";
}```   and I've also tried ```if($queryAddMessage){
   $msg = 'OK';
}```  with the same results  even tho the data gets sent to the database it's still going to the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should echo msg checked by js in php as OK

```
if($queryAddMessage){

                //code goes here
                echo 'OK';
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use a jQuery form validation plugin to validate form and its easier than using AJAX for the same.